# Fastest way to bruteforce a 6 character password

Tags: python, multithreading, brute-force

I am trying to find a faster way to brute force a 6 character password in format `abc123` (3 lower case letters and 3 numbers). It must include hashing the password and comparing it. I use random iteration and multithreading:

```
import string
from itertools import product
from time import time
import threading
import random

password = input("write your 3 letter 3 number password here: ")
hashed = hash(password)
start = time()

def product_loop(hashing, generator):
    for p in generator:
        global stop_threads
        if stop_threads:
            break
        if hash(''.join(p)) == hashing:
            print('\nPassword:', ''.join(p))
            print(hash(''.join(p)))
            stop_threads = True
            end = time()
            print('Total time: %.2f seconds' % (end - start))
            return ''.join(p)
    return False

def bruteforce(hashing, max_nchar=8):
    for l in range(6, max_nchar + 1):
        if stop_threads:
            break
        print("\t..%d char" % l)
        generator = product(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 26) + random.sample(string.digits, 10), repeat=int(l))
        p = product_loop(hashing, generator)
        if p is not False:
            return p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop_threads = False
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t7 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))
    t8 = threading.Thread(target=bruteforce,args=((hashed,)))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t5.start()
    t6.start()
    t7.start()
    t8.start()
```

Comment: Randomness isn't faster, it's slower. You still have to try all the options in the worst cast, so it's just adding the overhead of generating random numbers (and avoiding duplicate tries). Threads also don't make it faster, since the switching between threads will add more overhead than saving time - especially for a task this trivial - but mainly because what you're doing doesn't get sped up by multi-threading, since your program still only does one thing at a time.

Comment: thanks for the heads up but is there something similar to multithreading that can speed it up

Comment: If your computer has multiple CPUs, you might want to consider using multi-processing rather than multithreading.  As stated above, multithreading won't help you in Python.  There really is nothing better to do than to try all of them in order.

Answer (score 0):

try em all in order, not many faster ways